# Assign a test to multiple testers in Test Manager 2010

Tags: testcase, microsoft-test-manager

Is this possible?  Or would I have to create a copy of an existing test and assign one test to each tester?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to create a copy of your Test Case this is not necessary.

You can add two (or more) Test Suites to your Test Plan with the same requirement or with the same set of Test Cases and then assign them to different testers.

**EDIT:**

In your Test Plan you can create as many Test Suites as you want (e.g. "Functional Testing", "Quick Testing"). In each 'base' Test Suite you can add requirements (new test suites under your base test suite). The test cases of each requirement are automatically added. Now you can assign testers for each requirement or you can select a single test case under your requirements and assign a tester for each test case separately.

These are some good references:

[link1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167335/Software-Testing-with-Visual-Studio-2010)
[link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286739.aspx)

Comment: So, normal use then would be to have different test suites for different users?

Comment: I think it's the only way to assign multiple testers on the same test. Of course, this may produce different results from each tester. I don't know if this is what you actually want.

Comment: What I'm imagining is a system that's tested by a number of different users.  I would say User A and User B... go test our app.  And return the results to me.  So, they would follow the test plan for each test and pass or fail each step based on the expected results.  So, sounds like I need to have different test suites for each different user.

Comment: Ok, that was my misunderstood. By your title I thought that 'test' refers to a single test case.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning multiple testers is possible when a test case has multiple configurations.

I.e.: Tester A can be assigned to a test case with configuration *"Windows 7"* while Tester B can be assigned to the *same test case* but with configuration *"Windows 2008"*.

[**MSDN** - How to: Assign Who Will Run the Tests in a Test Plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286739.aspx)

> Note: If different testers are assigned to different configurations for the
>   same test, Multiple is displayed in Testers.